# android httpost request always return 404

Tags: android, base64

the following code is for make and httpost request to a server always response 404
but if i make the same request on postman works fine i send only one parameter on post an base 64 image string

```
private class SendData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
       // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        try{
            MobileUtil.HTTP_PARAMS = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(MobileUtil.HTTP_PARAMS, MobileUtil.HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(MobileUtil.HTTP_PARAMS, MobileUtil.HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            MobileUtil.HTTP_CLIENT = new DefaultHttpClient(MobileUtil.HTTP_PARAMS);
            MobileUtil.HTTP_CLIENT = sslClient(MobileUtil.HTTP_CLIENT);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://aplicacion.fractal.com.pe:9090/fractalMobile/mobile/guardarFotoTest");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("foto",encodedImage));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse resp = MobileUtil.HTTP_CLIENT.execute(post);
            Log.d("Info",resp.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            Log.d("Info",resp.getStatusLine().toString());
            String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
            Log.d("Info",respStr);
            if(respStr.equals("1"))
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Se Realizo la Operacion con Exito",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
       }  catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   return null;
}

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
     super.onPostExecute(s);
  }
 }
```

and i try to debug but don't know what is wrong on postman the request response with 1 if ok and 0 if go wrong
any idea how to make the request

Comment: for me postman reports '404' - is this a local server, or is it a valid public address?

Comment: its a valid public address maybe theyre doing a update on server but its works for me